# Multi-tenant routing with Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Our app is multi-tenant by organisation. A user can switch organisations in the app and the data will be filtered for that organisation. We'd like the navigation model to update the orgId to reflect the change in organisation. How can we dynamically configure the router nav model to update the organisationId? The following config doesn't work, as it requires an href, but I don't want to statically define the orgId:

```
config.map([
  { route: 'org/:orgId/users'], name: 'users', moduleId: 'users/list', nav: true 
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason it is required to add an HREF property is because you are attempting to use `nav: true` and Aurelia doesn't know how to add in an `orgId` that you haven't told it about.  Simply set that to false and loop over the routes to build your own navigation model and this issue goes away.